# Class-Responsibility-Collaborators (CRC) Cards template

Tags: tables, templates

I'm struggling with making a CRC card template, as the following one:

[image: A CRC Card template]

May anybody help me?

Ps. Add another row between Superclasses and Subclassess called Interfaces, please.

Comment: please upload your code as a MWE

Comment: I deleted yesterday because it did not compile.

Comment: How wide should your table be with respect to the textwidth? Should both columns be equally wide? If not, how wide should they be?

Comment: Both columns equally wide

Comment: Have you tried https://www.tablesgenerator.com/?

Comment: Start with something like: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
some text & other text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`